# I am currently working on a bot which shows value of anything how can I set value to 1 iif there are no args

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const value = message.content.split(' ')[2]
  if(!value) let value = 1;
  const value2show = 50000000 * value;
  let tro = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor("Sɱαɾƚx Gαɱιɳɠ YT", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/701780003959996497/2354797acbac60d124a80de2c3e52191.png?size=256")
  .setFooter("Bot made by Sɱαɾƚx Gαɱιɳɠ YT")
  .setTitle("Pepe Trophy")
  .setDescription(`Pepe Trophy x${value} costs **⏣${value2show}**`)
  .setTimestamp()
  message.lineReplyNoMention(tro)
```

I want that if there is no value it set the value to 1
thank for help.

Comment: `let value = 1;` -> `value = 1;`

Comment: I got it thanks for your answer :)